# How to install packages or natively compile package on a minimal Linux kernel compiled with Buildroot

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, buildroot

I enconter a problem I hope to be solved quickly.

I have grace to BUILDROOT compile a Linux zImage Kernel, build a rootfs, have a bootloader, so everething is right.

But at the boot, the system is so minimal that i don't have got some package manager like apt-get, yum, etc....

Despite the fact i've got the network (wget is possible), I don't know how to have a simply gcc in my host (Buildroot don't permit to compile gcc anymore)
or more simply a package manager.

It is so boring to cross compile everything that I think the better solution is to apt-get packages, resolve dependencies and install it for an ARM architecture..

I recompile with Package manager options including IPKG and OPKG but the repositories don't work and the commands return nothing (I.E. ipkg --list, etc..)

Did someone had the same problems and what is the best way to have a good Package Manager on a minimal system compiled and build grace to Buildroot.

What is the best way to have anymore a Native compile toolchain on the ARM host ?

Thanks to your answers

My purpose is to natively compile my code including -lm -lpthread and LIRC module and header files on this minimal host system.

Stefan, France

---- additional informations ---

hello,

i refresh this tag for set informations :

recently buildroot does no longer permit natively compile gcc package
even if make and other tools are available on the recent buildroot distribution

gcc and other tags are marked as deprecated

so it is needed / obligated to cross compile on the host
so what i did

for convenience, i've the Makefile for my code with dependencies
for pthread and lirc_client

If anybody interested, ask me,

stef, France

Comment: *"It is so boring to cross compile everything..."*  -- So you think native compilation is exciting?  *"Buildroot don't permit to compile gcc anymore"* -- Then use an old version of Buildroot to put a toolchain on the target.

Comment: @sawdust older version may not work with newer kernel.

Comment: @sawdust we want to create a fully contained development environment. The cross-compiler only runs on Linux_x86/64 so we would need to create a VM running on windows and then transfer the build artifacts from the VM to the target.

Answer (score 5):

The Buildroot reference documentation has plenty of details about these questions. Please see http://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#faq-no-compiler-on-target and http://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#faq-no-binary-packages.

Answer (score 0):

I've added dpkg inside buildroot in order to have dpkg on my board... it was really easy to do.
The only thing I had to hack is to create  a fake `ldconfig`.

Comment: Will that enable me to add `gcc` natively?

Comment: Nope! It just allows you to use a packet manager to distribute your own packages