# Which linux flavor is running

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kubernetes, minikube

I want to find out the linux flavor running on the vm created using minikube-kubernetes.
I log in to the vm and do a cat /proc/version
`Linux version 4.9.13 gcc version 5.4.0 (Buildroot 2017.02)`. 
Can someone tell me which flavor this is?
Obviously not ubuntu as none of the commands man, apt-get work.

Answer (score 6):

```
cat /etc/*release
```

This works across most distributions.

Comment: It gives me an unfamiliar output. Could you explain. NAME=Buildroot, VERSION=2017.20, ID=buildroot, PRETTY_NAME="buildroot 2017.02"

Comment: According to Google Buildroot apparently is an embedded version of Linux similar to BusyBox.

Comment: More information is also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907093/how-to-install-packages-or-natively-compile-package-on-a-minimal-linux-kernel-co

Answer (score 5):

The minikube distro is custom built using buildroot. It is meant to be a minimal distro and does not include a package manager or package repository.

- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/tree/master/deploy/iso/minikube-iso
- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/contributors/minikube_iso.md

Answer (score 0):

`lsb_release -ai` but you might need to install `lsb` module.

Comment: i am not sure of which package manager is running because i don't understand the linux flavor in the VM

Comment: do you either `yum` or `yast`? you can test this by typing and terminal and press "Enter"

Comment: `bash: lsb_release: command not found` means lsb module is not installed

Comment: Kinda looks like then it is non `LSB` compliant system then. It is neither `RHEL` based nor SUSE based or Ubuntu based as you have specified